# automation process to install a third party application in winxp

Tags: windows-xp

Hi I am working in automobile production environment and using the windchill 9.1 application software on winxp clients (500+nos). if windcill has released new patch I need to update the patch for every one. in this process I need to uninstall windchill workgroup manger software (WGM) older version and install new version with patch. so I need to uninstall old version and install new one in sam path ex: c:\abd\ERB-92 . It is java based installation application , in this process it will ask us to select language after next then select location to be installed on local drive. then click on then Done. now I need to automate this process.

help me out if you know process or application is there

Answer (score 1):

Check out [AutoIt GUI Scripting](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/).

> AutoIt v3 is a freeware BASIC-like scripting language designed for automating the Windows GUI and general scripting. It uses a combination of simulated keystrokes, mouse movement and window/control manipulation in order to automate tasks in a way not possible or reliable with other languages (e.g. VBScript and SendKeys). AutoIt is also very small, self-contained and will run on all versions of Windows out-of-the-box with no annoying "runtimes" required!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Preferably you'd repackage the installer in an MSI package that does the uninstall + install silently for you. This can then be distributed using plain Active Directory (or some more heavy-weight management suite) without the users or you having to visit or do anything to the clients or anyone having to be an administrator.

Tools for MSI packaging are plentiful, one is [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/).

The [Appdeploy](http://www.appdeploy.com/packages) web site may have additional information about your software if there's no enterprise deployment information available from the manufacturer/developer.

Comment: +1 Love Advanced Installer